# Fragment Stack Management

Tags: android, fragment

I need some help in Fragment stack. I have a scenarios. In that scenarios, We have four fragments A , B , C and D. I have added all the fragments in back stack using add method of FragmentTransaction. I want to swipe D to B without removing D in stack. As I have used below method for that. But it is removing D in stack.

```
appCompatActivity.supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(fragmentName, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

Comment: BackStack is a record tool for fragment transaction operations, popBackStack(..) just reverts latest record in the stack.

When you do A -> B and add it to back stack, popping it will do B -> A. Let's say you did A -> B, followed by B -> C without adding it to back stack. Popping back stack will still do B -> A.

Comment: @mel We have requirement like as we have added in question.

Comment: Soni I just explained how it works and what it is for, it doesn't store fragments or whatsoever, it's storing the transition you've done. You can manipulate how it behaves when you pop by this way. Note that it does steps even tho fragment is not there anymore.

Comment: @Mel Is it possible to achieve using fragments?

Comment: I have a library for it that makes navigation like that easily possible, but then you'd have to use the library instead of `addToBackStack()` in your code.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Which library you have used? Could you share it if possible?

Comment: Sure, see [here](https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/tree/3bb349ce995a48a7f93c13c3723e346f359ba54f/simple-stack-example-basic-java-fragment/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/navigationexamplefrag)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use viewpager?

[The easiest way to work with ViewPager](https://medium.com/@cdmunoz/the-easiest-way-to-work-with-viewpager-and-without-fragments-c62ec3e8b9f3)